# Cypress how to deal with one iframe into another iframe

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-iframe

The main goal is to get access to the input field and submit some data.
Problem - These elements are located in one iframe (we can't add there any attributes like id, etc) which is wrapped into another iframe (I was able to get access to it by id).
The top iframe is accessible using  `cy.frameLoaded('#3ds-iframe');`
The lower iframe isn't accessible using `cy.frameLoaded('#cko-3ds2-iframe');` or `cy.frameLoaded('[name="cko-3ds2-iframe"]')`
[image: DOM elements screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way I found works with nested iframes, at least with very simple HTML.

- Using `.enter()` which is part of the `cypress-iframe` package, move inside the first iframe.
- Using `getBody()` helper from same package, location the 2nd iframe.
- Use conventional Cypress commands (from [Working with iframes in Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/)) to extract the body of the the nested iframe.
- Use Cypress command `.within()` to focus the next commands inside that 2nd iframe.

```js
cy.enter('#iframe1').then(getBody => {
  getBody().find('#iframe2')
    .its('0.contentDocument')
    .its('body').within(() => {
      // working inside nested iframe
      cy.get('div').should('contain', 'Inside iframe2')
    })
})
```

This may need extra steps if the 2nd iframe takes longer to load than the outer iframe. The `cypress-iframe` command only checks the content of the outer frame, but hopefully the inner frame is also ready in that time period.

---

This is the HTML I tested

```html
<iframe id="iframe1" width="300" height="200" src="./iframe2.html">
  #document
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <iframe id="iframe2" width="300" height="200" src="./iframe-content.html">
        #document
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <div>Inside iframe2</div>
          </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```